# Reading an int from an API call

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I'm a newbie when it comes to android programming. I have been able to program a little bit on my program but now I have a problem.

I have created a working api service with different methods and one of the methods returns an int number. What I wanna do in android is that I wanna use httpurlconnection and get my int number from the api, so I for example can have like this:

```
Int b=(value returned from api call)
If(b==1){
}
```

Comment: what you mean ?You wanna learn calling an api or handle int?

Comment: You question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I think Luis helped me with his answer:)

Comment: Great! Can you please mark my answer as the correct one please? I'm trying to hoard some reputation here ;) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should treat all API values as strings.

Just do something like:

```
Int b = Int.pasrseInt(value returned from api call as string);
```